# How to achieve less intrusive workflow in Perforce? (Fed up with read-only files)

Tags: perforce

At work, we use a version control system called Perforce. Bizarrely, it makes all the files downloaded from the repo readonly. It then demands you tell it  (`p4 open`) whenever you want to edit any one of them. This is tedious, and really interrupts my concentration--I just want to edit a file on my computer, not think about version control.

Is it possible to have a less intrusive workflow? I'd like to edit files on my computer as I see fit. Then when I'm done, group and title them into a commit/changelist.

Comment: What editor do you use? Some editors have perforce plugins that will help with this

Comment: You could also try to get your workplace to use something else!

Comment: If you would rather "not think about version control", then don't use it.  Just edit your file, give it to one of your coworkers, and ask them to deal with that "bizarre" and "intrusive" Perforce thing for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can totally control this workflow.

Here's what to do:

1. Change your client options to specify "allwrite"
2. re-sync your files and they are all now left writable
3. Edit files as you wish
4. When you are ready to submit, run 'p4 reconcile'. It will figure out what files you have edited, what files you have added, what files you have deleted.
5. Submit your changes

As you say, edit your files on your computer as you see fit. Then, when you are done, group and title them into a changelist and submit them.

Here's some docs for the "allwrite" option: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html

Answer (score 0):

If you work in Visual Studio, then I would highly recommend checking out [P4VS](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/visual-studio-plug-in). I think that would resolve most, if not all, of the issues you're having with the workflow.

You could also use the "Allwrite" option in your workspace, which will leave all files writable. If you go this route, you'll still need to mark the files for edit and group them into a changelist to a submit, but it won't interrupt you while you're programming.